# Не(свойственны)

Tags: частица-не

Как пишется не - слитно или раздельно? В его творчестве присутствуют такие темы и мотивы, которые несвойственны творчеству его старшего поколения.

Comment: @янааа, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

В его творчестве присутствуют такие темы и мотивы, которые несвойственны творчеству его старшего поколения.

Несвойственны - прилагательное, его можно заменить синонимом чужды, значит, слитное написание с НЕ.

Comment: Людмила, не всегда же так: если можно заменить синонимом, то слитно. Вот слова (не)низок или (не)мал неужели Вы слитно напишете?! А синонимом еще как можно заменить.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно и слитное, и раздельное написание в зависимости от смыслового акцента: на утверждении или на отрицании.

Розенталь: В зависимости от смысла не с краткими прилагательными, как и с полными, пишется то слитно, то раздельно; ср.: *наша семья небогата* (примерно то же, что бедна) – *наша семья не богата* (т.е. среднего достатка); *эта девушка некрасива* (утверждается отрицательный признак) – *эта девушка не красива* (отрицается положительный признак), *адрес неизвестен* (утверждается «неизвестность») – *адрес не известен* (отрицается «известность»). Ср. также: *Невелика беда*. – *Не велика, казалось бы, эта дистанция для стайеров*.

Answer (score 1):

Да, но Розенталь приводит примеры кратких прилагательных, в которых по факту широко применяется слитное написание. Небогат, некрасив, неизвестен, невелик, неширок, невысок... *Оно конешно*! А вот интересно, что бы сказал Розенталь о слове *ненизок*? Вот *невысок* точно есть, но *ненизок* точно нету! Просто по факту нет, не встречается. Языку не нужно это слово, вот его и нет.

Так что здесь нужно перво-наперво смотреть в словарях. Есть слово с НЕ — тогда надо думать, как писать: слитно или раздельно. А если в словарях нет слова с НЕ — и думать нечего, надо писать раздельно.

Вот "не свойственны" я бы совершенно точно всегда писал раздельно.

Comment: Ваше мнение негласно разделяют работники Грамоты.ру. В своих ответах на вопросы, не связанные с данной темой, они всегда пишут "не свойственны" раздельно.